# Swift User Creation Not Detecting UIText Length

Tags: swift, if-statement

working on user creation. Pretty simple idea, the email can't be `nil` or empty, `password` and `confirm password` have to be equal to be each other, and `password` has to be over 6 characters. For whatever reason, this last condition is always passing true. Because of this, users are able to register with a 1 letter or number password. Why would this be happening?

```
else if(emailTxt.text != "" &&  passwordTxt.text == confirmPassTxt.text && passwordTxt.text?.characters.count > 6){}
```

Also, something interesting, I can obviously compare the values because this code to get an password mismatch works perfectly fine.

```
else if(emailTxt.text != "" &&  passwordTxt.text != confirmPassTxt.text)
```

This will return `true` or `false` correctly. So the problems come from counting the characters, but I just can't see it right now. Simple mistake?

Comment: Because it is optional? Remove the questionmark from the last condition...

Comment: Already tried, switched `?` to `!` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Works fine with my answer below though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting way I solved this. Because I never gave an option for `Swift` to choose if the password WASN'T above 6 characters, it just assumed it was? Not sure why, but adding another condition like this worked.

```
lse if(emailTxt.text != "" &&  passwordTxt.text == confirmPassTxt.text && passwordTxt.text?.characters.count < 6 && confirmPassTxt.text?.characters.count < 6){
```

As you can see it is essentially the same except I changed the `>` symbols to `<`. Working perfectly fine now